# Relation little-o/big-o

Tags: notation, taylor-expansion

Currently, I am studying kernel regressions. The problem I have is in understanding the relation between big-o and little-o. The following changes (in two different papers) occur:

$ \frac{h^{2(j-1)}}{N} \int_0^{\infty}(K(x))^2 \cdot x^{2j} f(hx)dx = O\left( \frac{h^{j2-1}}{N}\right) = o\left( \left( \frac{h^j}{hN^{1/2}}\right)^2\right) = o((h^j)^2) $

and

$ Bias (\hat{f}(x)) = \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x)] -f(x) = \frac{1}{v!}f^{(v)}(x)h^vk_v(k)+o(h^v)$

Then taking $v=2$ we have:

$ Bias (\hat{f}(x)) = \frac{1}{2!}f^{(2)}(x)h^2k_2(k)+O(h^4)$

The last two equations follow from a Taylor expansion. Hence, the $f^{(v)}$ denotes the order of the derivative. Now my problem is that I do not see how little-o becomes big-o and how big-o becomes little-o.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that I did not dive in Taylor part, but for $O,o$ we have following general properties:
$$o(g) \subset O(g)$$
$$O(x^n) \subset o(x^{n+1}), x \to 0.$$
Some authors prefer to write equality, which exact meaning, though, is subset.